# Cpp/Eigen convert float to a list of bytes

Tags: c++, casting, eigen

I have a `class A` and this class has a class member `DATA` like this:

```
class A{
   public:
   A();

   privat:
   Eigen::Matrix<unsigned char, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic> DATA;
};
```

Now lets assume I want to store float(32bit) values into that matrix, but without changing the scalar Type of DATA is that possible? Like could I store the float as a list of bytes and than somehow cast it back to float when I need it? How would i do that?

Comment: With a union or memcpy

Comment: You could try to use Eigen::Map

Comment: @user253751 how?